# Show listview picture and details using picasso

Tags: android

i am try to display and image in listview in android and it is not showing i have beening trying it for a while now. i have a database and i have put in url or images thier name and id .. and i want the listview to show the images and thier detail.
but it is giving me errors ... can anyone help me..
it is telling me category not found..

```
package com.example.cann;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CategoryActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "category";
    public static final String TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT = "categories_count";
    public static final String TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO = "categories_logo";

    private static final String URL_CATEGORY = "http://10.0.2.2/music/selectm.php";

    // albums JSONArray
    JSONArray categories = null;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // private ListView lv;
    private BaseAdapter mAdapter;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoryList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Log.d("onCreate: ", "Yep");


        new LoadComments().execute();
    }

    public void yess(){
        // get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setDivider(null);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, "Item selected: " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Uncomment this to start a new Activity for a chosen item
                /* Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ItemListActivity.class);

                String category_id = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.category_id)).getText()
                        .toString();
                i.putExtra("category_id", category_id);

                startActivity(i);*/
            }
        });
    }
    public void upd(){

        categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();    
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_CATEGORY);
        try {

            categories  = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c =categories.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT);
                String category_logo = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT, songs_count);
                map.put(TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO, category_logo);

                categoryList.add(map);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList

                }

                mAdapter = new CategoryListAdapter(CategoryActivity.this,
                        categoryList);
                getListView().setAdapter(mAdapter);

                // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
                pDialog.dismiss();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                        upd();

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

            pDialog.dismiss();
            yess();
                    }
                });
        }
    }


}




package com.example.cann;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CategoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> urls;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static final String CATEGORY_LOGO_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/demi.jpg";

    public CategoryListAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items) {
        mContext = context;
        urls = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getItem(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView category_name;
        ImageView category_logo;
        TextView item_count;
        TextView item_id;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_category, parent,
                false);

        resultp = urls.get(position);

        category_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        category_logo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_category_logo);
        item_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songs_count);
        item_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_id);

        category_name.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_NAME));
        item_count.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT));
        item_id.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_ID));

        // Picasso image loader library starts here
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(CATEGORY_LOGO_URL
                        + resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO)) // Photo URL
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) // This image will be displayed while photo URL is loading
                .error(R.drawable.error) // if error shows up during downloading
                .fit().centerCrop() // settings
                .into(category_logo); // we put it into our layout component (imageview)

        return view;
    }

}
```

and i have tested my php script and it is displaying image

```
require("config.inc.php");

$query = "Select * FROM music";

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();

        $post["TAG_ID"]    = $row["id"];

        $post[" TAG_NAME"]    = $row["Artist"];
        $post["TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT"]  = $row["Song"];

        $post["TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO"] = $row["Artpics"];


        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }

    echo json_encode($response);


} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```

**my Logcat**

```
 09-13 07:38:59.020: W/System.err(1315): org.json.JSONException: No value for id
    09-13 07:38:59.220: W/System.err(1315):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
    09-13 07:38:59.220: W/System.err(1315):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
    09-13 07:38:59.260: W/System.err(1315):     at com.example.cann.CategoryActivity.upd(CategoryActivity.java:103)
    09-13 07:38:59.260: W/System.err(1315):     at com.example.cann.CategoryActivity$LoadComments.doInBackground(CategoryActivity.java:148)
    09-13 07:38:59.270: W/System.err(1315):     at com.example.cann.CategoryActivity$LoadComments.doInBackground(CategoryActivity.java:1)
    09-13 07:38:59.270: W/System.err(1315):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    09-13 07:38:59.270: W/System.err(1315):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    09-13 07:38:59.270: W/System.err(1315):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    09-13 07:38:59.270: W/System.err(1315):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    09-13 07:38:59.270: W/System.err(1315):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    09-13 07:38:59.270: W/System.err(1315):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Exception throws due no value for id in json can you please post response?

Comment: what do you mean by response

Comment: do you mean   {"success":1,"message":"Post Available!","posts":[{"TAG_ID":"5"," TAG_NAME":"Demi lovato","TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT":"Heart attack","TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2\/demi.jpg"}]}

Comment: is it your response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to replace this peace of code :**

```
String id = c.getString("TAG_ID");
String name = c.getString("TAG_NAME");
String songs_count = c.getString("TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT");
String category_logo = c.getString("TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO");
```

**Also remove space from this :**

```
$post[" TAG_NAME"] replace to $post["TAG_NAME"]
```

**Note :** your using wrong key to get data from json.

```
public class CategoryActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "category";
    public static final String TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT = "categories_count";
    public static final String TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO = "categories_logo";

    private static final String URL_CATEGORY = "http://10.0.2.2/music/selectm.php";
    private BaseAdapter mAdapter;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setDivider(null);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,int position, long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, "Item selected: " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Uncomment this to start a new Activity for a chosen item
                /* Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ItemListActivity.class);

                String category_id = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.category_id)).getText()
                        .toString();
                i.putExtra("category_id", category_id);

                startActivity(i);*/
            }
        });
        new LoadComments().execute();
    }

    class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_CATEGORY);
            try {
                JSONArray categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                    String id = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_ID");
                    String name = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_NAME");
                    String songs_count = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT");
                    String category_logo = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO");

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT, songs_count);
                    map.put(TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO, category_logo);

                    categoryList.add(map);
                }
            }catch (Throwable e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return categoryList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            mAdapter = new CategoryListAdapter(CategoryActivity.this,result);
            lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: new errors                                                                  W/dalvikvm(1277): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a6dba8)
09-13 08:30:29.969: E/AndroidRuntime(1277): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-13 08:30:29.969: E/AndroidRuntime(1277): Process: com.example.cann, PID: 1277
09-13 08:30:29.969: E/AndroidRuntime(1277): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
-13

Comment: thank you for your ansewr just a little problem .. the details are showing but the image is constantly showing .. the picture in                          .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) thats the error picture not the ..picture it is meant to show

Comment: i not getting ur problem cam you please explain more ?

Comment: it is just that if i click on the emulator before it finishes downloading it showes the .error(R.drawable.error) picture . but i want it to still load like lazyloading how do i implement that.